# Google Drive on Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, online-accounts, google-drive

I installed the Google drive on lubuntu (after first trying to install odrive which worked out to be a nodrive), using the online accounts (gnome-control-center online-accounts). I can the drive (yippee!) and the files (wauw!) but the filenames are all scrambled!

[image: Screen print with scrambled names]

What am I doing wrong?
Desktop = LXQt 0.17.0
Ubuntu = 21.10

Comment: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/mounting-google-drive-on-xfce-or-mate.html

follow the ocamlfuse part